How to read a netcdf file with multiple dimensions using terra in R?
I have a netcdf file that has the dimensions of lat, lon, time and effect. The file also have 3 different variables: rn, prec and tair.
I want to read the file using terra, but I get unexpected results when I do so:
# store the url where the netcdf data is hosted
url = "https://github.com/qquusshh/data_so/raw/main/data.nc"

# download the netcdf data in the current directory with the name "data.nc"
download.file(url, "data.nc", mode = "wb")

# read the file
terra::rast("data.nc")
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 360, 3, 2160  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -0.5, 2.5, -180, 180  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. :  
#> sources     : data.nc:rn  (720 layers) 
#>               data.nc:prec  (720 layers) 
#>               data.nc:tair  (720 layers) 
#> varnames    : rn 
#>               prec 
#>               tair 
#> names       : rn_ef~9.5_1, rn_ef~8.5_1, rn_ef~7.5_1, rn_ef~6.5_1, rn_ef~5.5_1, rn_ef~4.5_1, ...

I would expect the nrow to be lat (180), ncol to be lon (360), nlyr to be time (3) and somehow another dimension containing the effect.
When I use xarray from python, everything works perfectly:
# import the xarray library
import xarray as xr

# open the data
xr.open_dataset("data.nc")

output:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 180, lon: 360, time: 3, effect: 4)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 89.5 88.5 87.5 86.5 85.5 ... -86.5 -87.5 -88.5 -89.5
  * lon      (lon) float64 -179.5 -178.5 -177.5 -176.5 ... 177.5 178.5 179.5
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2019-12-29 2019-12-30 2019-12-31
  * effect   (effect) object 'inst' 'short' 'long' 'static'
Data variables:
    rn       (effect, lat, lon, time) float64 ...
    prec     (effect, lat, lon, time) float64 ...
    tair     (effect, lat, lon, time) float64 ...


Somehow it's almost always ncdf when there are issues with dims. sf::gdal_utils("info", "data.nc") returns the following warning: "GDAL Message 1: The dataset has several variables that could be identified as vector fields, but not all share the same primary dimension. Consequently they will be ignored."

It might be worth trying the ncdf4 package instead of terra. You can open the file with nc <- ncdf4::nc_open("data.nc"), then read (for example) variable rn with ncdf4::ncvar_get(nc, "rn").

By the way, the issue is not about multiple dimensions per se because GDAL (used by terra) does not fail with other nc files created according to CF-1.8.  Right now, the dimensions of your variables are in this order: [time, lon, lat, effect]. What if we changed these using aperm() and ncdf4::ncvar_put()?

What you have here is a file that is not abiding by the netCDF standards and goals: "A netCDF dataset includes information defining the data it contains".
Your file contains no attributes of any significant nature (only _FillValue for the "lat" and "lon" dimensions, and units and calendar for the "time" dimension). Consequently, no package can correctly interpret what is in the file. That includes xarray: while it nicely presents what it finds in the file, there is no interpretation of any kind (what terra tries to do and fails at - same goes for the stars package if you tried), except for the "time" dimension which happens to have the 2 relevant attributes.
You might find code that correctly guesses that "lon" stands for "longitude", and "lat" for "latitude", but that is not how self-respecting packages (like terra and stars) work. In my opinion, terra should have given up on this file with a message that required attributes are missing, rather than come up with the "solution" you were presented with.
Your best way forward is to process this "manually" into an array with dimnames set and then convert that to a terra::SpatRaster or a stars::stars object.
And tell your data provider to clean up their act.

Working with NetCDF files for the first time using {ncdf4} to be honest, and basically I only have half an idea what I'm actually doing, so I'm curious what I'll learn from the comments after posting this.
As already mentioned in the comments, {terra} fails to read this out of the box because GDAL fails to do so, c.f. behaviour in QGIS. And since this is not a problem  because of the multiple dimensions per se, my guess was to check on the dimensions in depth.
At first I wanted to raise questions because of the effect dimension in general (apart from the obvious X and Y when dealing with spatial data, I rather thought of Z and/or time as possible other dimensions), but according to the NetCDF User's Guide, this seems to be fine:

A dimension may be used to represent a real physical dimension, for example, time, latitude, longitude, or height. A dimension might also be used to index other quantities, for example station or model-run-number.

So the dimensions seem valid but does their order play a role? Quoting from CF-1.8 in this regard:

If any or all of the dimensions of a variable have the interpretations of "date or time" (T), "height or depth" (Z), "latitude" (Y), or "longitude" (X) then we recommend, but do not require [...], those dimensions to appear in the relative order T, then Z, then Y, then X in the CDL definition corresponding to the file. All other dimensions should, whenever possible, be placed to the left of the spatiotemporal dimensions.

According to this convention, if I got it right, your dimensions should be in the following order: [effect, time, lat, lon] but they currently are [time, lon, lat, effect]. So I changed these and was hoping for an easy fix but ended up with a SpatRaster object with 3 rows times 4 columns and 194,400 layers (180 * 360 * 3). Obviously this was not the desired output but at least showed that order does influence the output, so I continued dissassembling and restructuring the dataset:
library(ncdf4)

nc <- nc_open("data.nc")
nc
#> File data.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):
#> 
#>      3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
#>         double rn[time,lon,lat,effect]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         double prec[time,lon,lat,effect]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         double tair[time,lon,lat,effect]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#> 
#>      4 dimensions:
#>         lat  Size:180 
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         lon  Size:360 
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         time  Size:3 
#>             units: days since 2019-12-29
#>             calendar: proleptic_gregorian
#>         effect  Size:4

# get variables
rn <- ncvar_get(nc, "rn")
prec <- ncvar_get(nc, "prec")
tair <- ncvar_get(nc, "tair")

# change order of array dims to: lon, lat, effect, time
ord <- c(2, 3, 4, 1)

rn_t <- aperm(rn, ord)
prec_t <- aperm(prec, ord)
tair_t <- aperm(tair, ord)

# define dimensions
dim_lon <- ncdim_def("lon", units = "", vals = ncvar_get(nc, "lon"))
dim_lat <- ncdim_def("lat", units = "", vals = ncvar_get(nc, "lat"))
dim_effect <- ncdim_def("effect", units = "", vals = 1:4)
dim_time <- ncdim_def("time", units = "days since 2019-12-29", calendar = "proleptic_gregorian", vals = ncvar_get(nc, "time"))

# define variables
var_rn <- ncvar_def("rn", units = "", dim = list(dim_lon, dim_lat, dim_effect, dim_time), missval = NA, prec = "float")
var_prec <- ncvar_def("prec", units = "", dim = list(dim_lon, dim_lat, dim_effect, dim_time), missval = NA, prec = "float")
var_tair <- ncvar_def("tair", units = "", dim = list(dim_lon, dim_lat, dim_effect, dim_time), missval = NA, prec = "float")

# create nc file, put variables, close file
nc_new <- nc_create("foobar.nc", list(var_rn, var_prec, var_tair), force_v4 = TRUE)
nc_new
#> File foobar.nc (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):
#> 
#>      3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
#>         float rn[lon,lat,effect,time]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         float prec[lon,lat,effect,time]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#>         float tair[lon,lat,effect,time]   (Contiguous storage)  
#>             _FillValue: NaN
#> 
#>      4 dimensions:
#>         lon  Size:360 
#>             long_name: lon
#>         lat  Size:180 
#>             long_name: lat
#>         effect  Size:4 
#>             long_name: effect
#>         time  Size:3 
#>             units: days since 2019-12-29
#>             long_name: time
#>             calendar: proleptic_gregorian

ncvar_put(nc_new, "rn", rn_t)
ncvar_put(nc_new, "prec", prec_t)
ncvar_put(nc_new, "tair", tair_t)

nc_close(nc_new)

This does not feel very elegant, but seems to have worked in the end. This is now what is returned using {terra} after this basic modification of dimensions:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71

# 180 nrows, 360 ncols, 36 nlyrs (3 vars * 3 time * 4 effect)
r <- rast("foobar.nc")
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 360, 36  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> sources     : foobar.nc:rn  (12 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:prec  (12 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:tair  (12 layers) 
#> varnames    : rn 
#>               prec 
#>               tair 
#> names       : rn_ef~t=1_1, rn_ef~t=2_1, rn_ef~t=3_1, rn_ef~t=4_1, rn_ef~t=1_2, rn_ef~t=2_2, ... 
#> time (days) : 2019-12-29 to 2019-12-31

# check names
names(r)
#>  [1] "rn_effect=1_1"   "rn_effect=2_1"   "rn_effect=3_1"   "rn_effect=4_1"  
#>  [5] "rn_effect=1_2"   "rn_effect=2_2"   "rn_effect=3_2"   "rn_effect=4_2"  
#>  [9] "rn_effect=1_3"   "rn_effect=2_3"   "rn_effect=3_3"   "rn_effect=4_3"  
#> [13] "prec_effect=1_1" "prec_effect=2_1" "prec_effect=3_1" "prec_effect=4_1"
#> [17] "prec_effect=1_2" "prec_effect=2_2" "prec_effect=3_2" "prec_effect=4_2"
#> [21] "prec_effect=1_3" "prec_effect=2_3" "prec_effect=3_3" "prec_effect=4_3"
#> [25] "tair_effect=1_1" "tair_effect=2_1" "tair_effect=3_1" "tair_effect=4_1"
#> [29] "tair_effect=1_2" "tair_effect=2_2" "tair_effect=3_2" "tair_effect=4_2"
#> [33] "tair_effect=1_3" "tair_effect=2_3" "tair_effect=3_3" "tair_effect=4_3"

# subset by variable (12 layers left; 3 time * 4 effect)
r["rn"]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 360, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> source      : foobar.nc:rn 
#> varname     : rn 
#> names       : rn_ef~t=1_1, rn_ef~t=2_1, rn_ef~t=3_1, rn_ef~t=4_1, rn_ef~t=1_2, rn_ef~t=2_2, ... 
#> time (days) : 2019-12-29 to 2019-12-31

# subset by time (12 layers left; 3 vars * 4 effect)
r[[time(r) == as.Date("2019-12-29")]]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 360, 12  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> sources     : foobar.nc:rn  (4 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:prec  (4 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:tair  (4 layers) 
#> varnames    : rn 
#>               prec 
#>               tair 
#> names       : rn_ef~t=1_1, rn_ef~t=2_1, rn_ef~t=3_1, rn_ef~t=4_1, prec_~t=1_1, prec_~t=2_1, ... 
#> time (days) : 2019-12-29

# subset by effect (9 layers left; 3 vars * 3 time)
r["effect=1"]
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 180, 360, 9  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#> extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> sources     : foobar.nc:rn  (3 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:prec  (3 layers) 
#>               foobar.nc:tair  (3 layers) 
#> varnames    : rn 
#>               prec 
#>               tair 
#> names       : rn_ef~t=1_1, rn_ef~t=1_2, rn_ef~t=1_3, prec_~t=1_1, prec_~t=1_2, prec_~t=1_3, ... 
#> time (days) : 2019-12-29 to 2019-12-31


Your effort is commendable but your analysis is lacking and your solution is not very practical. The problem is that the file lacks attributes, not how it is stored internally: the whole purpose of netCDF is that it describes how its data is stored such that readers can correctly interpret it. What you do here is to fudge the data so that terra's guess is correct. See my answer for more details.

@Patrick Totally agree with you, that's not even quick but only dirty. But I didn't want to provide all the missing attributes myself to be honest... But good to know that this would probably solve reading issues on terras side.
